# Linked list node implementation with maximum code reuse

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

Currently as an exercise to practicing SOLID principles and basic data structures, I am trying to implement linked list type structures with as much code reuse as possible. Currently, I have:

```
package structures.linked;

public class SingleNode<T> {

    private T data;
    private SingleNode<T> next;

    public SingleNode(T data, SingleNode<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public SingleNode<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(SingleNode<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

}
```

and...

```
package structures.linked;

public class DoubleNode<T> extends SingleNode<T> {

    private DoubleNode<T> prev;

    public DoubleNode(T data, DoubleNode<T> next, DoubleNode<T> prev) {
        super(data, next);
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public DoubleNode<T> getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    public void setPrev(DoubleNode<T> prev) {
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public DoubleNode<T> getNext() {
        return (DoubleNode<T>) super.getNext();
    }

    public void setNext(DoubleNode<T> next) {
        super.setNext(next);
    }
}
```

It seems to me that `getNext()` inside of `DoubleNode<T>` is a violation of Liskov's substitution principle. Is this the case? Is there a better way to implement this while still reusing the code in `SingleNode<T>` and without breaking SOLID principles?

Comment: Hey Matthew, I think questions like this are better fit on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kuba will definitely be cross posting over there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using an abstract class with additional generic parameter:

```
public abstract class AbstracteNode<T, B extends AbstracteNode<T, ?>> {
    private T data;
    private B nextNode;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setNext(B inNextNode){
        this.nextNode = inNextNode;
    }

    public B getNext() {
        return nextNode;
    }
}
```

Then extending it with the correct types for B:
(In case of SingleNode you do this only for the reason that developers using it have only to provide T)

```
public class SingleNode<T> extends AbstracteNode<T, SingleNode<T>>{}
```

And

```
public class DoubleNode<T> extends AbstracteNode<T, DoubleNode<T>> {
    private DoubleNode<T> previousNode;

    public DoubleNode<T> getPrevious() {
        return previousNode;
    }

    public void setPrevious(DoubleNode<T> inPreviousNode) {
        this.previousNode = inPreviousNode;
    }
}
```

Now your test should work without code duplication and without casting:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        SingleNode<Integer> singleNode = new SingleNode<>();
        SingleNode<Integer> nextForSingle = singleNode.getNext();

        DoubleNode<Double> doubleNode = new DoubleNode<>();
        DoubleNode<Double> previousForDouble = doubleNode.getPrevious();
        DoubleNode<Double> nextForDouble = doubleNode.getNext();
    }
}
```